# How can I store a command in a variable in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, command

I would like to store a command to use at a later time in a variable (not the output of the command, but the command itself).

I have a simple script as follows:

```
command="ls";
echo "Command: $command"; #Output is: Command: ls

b=`$command`;
echo $b; #Output is: public_html REV test... (command worked successfully)
```

However, when I try something a bit more complicated, it fails. For example, if I make

```
command="ls | grep -c '^'";
```

The output is:

```
Command: ls | grep -c '^'
ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access grep: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '^': No such file or directory
```

How could I store such a command (with pipes/multiple commands) in a variable for later use?

Comment: Use a function!

Comment: See this post: [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead).

Comment: See also [Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia) and the similar https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 230, accepted):

Use eval:

```
x="ls | wc"
eval "$x"
y=$(eval "$x")
echo "$y"
```

Comment: $(...) is now recommended instead of `backticks`. 
  y=$(eval $x) 
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: while that has been confusing at start, it's running as expected in both ways. `eval` is fine. Thank you.

Comment: `eval` is an acceptable practice **only** if you trust your variables' contents. If you're running, say, `x="ls $name | wc"` (or even `x="ls '$name' | wc"`), then this code is a fast track to injection or privilege escalation vulnerabilities if that variable can be set by someone with less privileges. (Iterating over all subdirectories in `/tmp`, for instance? You'd better trust every single user on the system to not make one called `$'/tmp/evil-$(rm -rf $HOME)\'$(rm -rf $HOME)\'/'`).

Comment: `eval` is a huge bug magnet that should never be recommended without a warning about the risk of unexpected parsing behavior (even without malicious strings, as in @CharlesDuffy's example). For example, try `x='echo $(( 6 * 7 ))'` and then `eval $x`. You might expect that to print "42", but it probably won't. Can you explain why it doesn't work? Can you explain why I said "probably"? If the answers to those questions aren't obvious to you, you should never touch `eval`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson why... I have completely no idea (and I do follow what you said.. i took away `eval` in my script!)

Comment: @Student, try running `set -x` beforehand to log the commands run, which will make it easier to see what's happening.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that is a spectacular trick! I am pretty new to this, and did not learn it systematically. I think I should study some theory behind it for a while until I start making scripts again.. any good suggestions?

Comment: The [POSIX sh specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html) is the canonical source. Beyond that, I'm fond of the Wooledge wiki, which beyond the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) also hosts background such as the [BashParser](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser) page.

Comment: @Student I'd also recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) for pointing out common mistakes (and bad habits you shouldn't pick up).

Answer (score 116):

Do *not* use `eval`! It has a major risk of introducing arbitrary code execution.

#### [BashFAQ-50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) - I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail.

Put it in an array and expand all the words with double-quotes `"${arr[@]}"` to *not* let the `IFS` split the words due to [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

```
cmdArgs=()
cmdArgs=('date' '+%H:%M:%S')
```

and see the contents of the array inside. The `declare -p` allows  you see the contents of the array inside with each command parameter in separate indices. If one such argument contains spaces, quoting inside while adding to the array will prevent it from getting split due to Word-Splitting.

```
declare -p cmdArgs
declare -a cmdArgs='([0]="date" [1]="+%H:%M:%S")'
```

and execute the commands as

```
"${cmdArgs[@]}"
23:15:18
```

(or) altogether use a `bash` function to run the command,

```
cmd() {
   date '+%H:%M:%S'
}
```

and call the function as just

```
cmd
```

POSIX `sh` has no arrays, so the closest you can come is to build up a list of elements in the positional parameters. Here's a POSIX `sh` way to run a mail program

```
# POSIX sh
# Usage: sendto subject address [address ...]
sendto() {
    subject=$1
    shift
    first=1
    for addr; do
        if [ "$first" = 1 ]; then set --; first=0; fi
        set -- "$@" --recipient="$addr"
    done
    if [ "$first" = 1 ]; then
        echo "usage: sendto subject address [address ...]"
        return 1
    fi
    MailTool --subject="$subject" "$@"
}
```

Note that this approach can only handle simple commands with no redirections. It can't handle redirections, pipelines, for/while loops, if statements, etc

Another common use case is when running `curl` with multiple header fields and payload. You can always define args like below and invoke `curl` on the expanded array content

```
curlArgs=('-H' "keyheader: value" '-H' "2ndkeyheader: 2ndvalue")
curl "${curlArgs[@]}"
```

Another example,

```
payload='{}'
hostURL='http://google.com'
authToken='someToken'
authHeader='Authorization:Bearer "'"$authToken"'"'
```

now that variables are defined, use an array to store your command args

```
curlCMD=(-X POST "$hostURL" --data "$payload" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "$authHeader")
```

and now do a proper quoted expansion

```
curl "${curlCMD[@]}"
```

Comment: This does not work for me, I have tried `Command=('echo aaa | grep a')` and `"${Command[@]}"`, hoping it runs literally the command `echo aaa | grep a`. It doesn't. I wonder if there's a safe way replacing `eval`, but seems that each solution that has the same force as `eval` could be dangerous. Isn't it?

Comment: In short, how does this work if the original string contains a pipe '|'?

Comment: @Student, if your original string contains a pipe, then that string needs to go through the unsafe parts of the bash parser to be executed as code. Don't use a string in that case; use a function instead: `Command() { echo aaa | grep a; }` -- after which you can just run `Command`, or `result=$(Command)`, or the like.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy problem is it fails if I want to do `Command() {$1}; Command "echo aaa | grep a"`

Comment: @Student, right; but that fails **intentionally**, because what you're asking to do *is inherently insecure*.

Comment: @Student: I've added a note at the last to mention it doesn't work under certain conditions

Comment: `with no redirections. It can't handle redirections, pipelines, for/while loops, if statements,`, but there is an if:     if [ "$first" = 1 ]; then..

Comment: @Timo It's saying that you can't pass in an `if` statement to `sendto`; the fact that the code of the implementation contains an `if` statement and some other logic is unrelated to this restriction.

Comment: @tripleee, you mean pass logic as param to `sendto()` or as $1?

Comment: Yes, exactly. For example, you can't `sendto if true; then echo poo; fi` because it looks like you are sending `if true`, which in isolation is obviously a syntax error, and the following statements are unrelated to the `sendto` call.

Comment: @tripleee: a bit kudos for offering the bounty, wish I could share it with you and other useful contributors ;)

Answer (score 45):

```
var=$(echo "asdf")
echo $var
# => asdf
```

Using this method, the command is immediately evaluated and its return value is stored.

```
stored_date=$(date)
echo $stored_date
# => Thu Jan 15 10:57:16 EST 2015
# (wait a few seconds)
echo $stored_date
# => Thu Jan 15 10:57:16 EST 2015
```

The same with backtick

```
stored_date=`date`
echo $stored_date
# => Thu Jan 15 11:02:19 EST 2015
# (wait a few seconds)
echo $stored_date
# => Thu Jan 15 11:02:19 EST 2015
```

Using eval in the `$(...)` will not make it evaluated later:

```
stored_date=$(eval "date")
echo $stored_date
# => Thu Jan 15 11:05:30 EST 2015
# (wait a few seconds)
echo $stored_date
# => Thu Jan 15 11:05:30 EST 2015
```

**Using eval, it is evaluated when `eval` is used**:

```
stored_date="date" # < storing the command itself
echo $(eval "$stored_date")
# => Thu Jan 15 11:07:05 EST 2015
# (wait a few seconds)
echo $(eval "$stored_date")
# => Thu Jan 15 11:07:16 EST 2015
#                     ^^ Time changed
```

In the above example, if you need to run a command with arguments, put them in the string you are storing:

```
stored_date="date -u"
# ...
```

For Bash scripts this is rarely relevant, but one last note. Be careful with `eval`. Eval only strings you control, never strings coming from an untrusted user or built from untrusted user input.

Comment: This does not solve the original problem where the command contains a pipe '|'.

Comment: @Nate, note that `eval $stored_date` may be fine enough when `stored_date` only contains `date`, but `eval "$stored_date"` is much more reliable. Run `str=$'printf \' * %s\\n\' *'; eval "$str"` with and without the quotes around the final `"$str"` for an example. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I forgot about quoting. I'll bet my linter would have complained had I bothered to run it.

Comment: Tangentially, that's a [useless `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score 6):

For bash, store your command like this:

```
command="ls | grep -c '^'"
```

Run your command like this:

```
echo $command | bash
```

Comment: Not sure but perhaps this way of running the command has the same risks that the use of 'eval' has.

Comment: In addition, you are wrecking the contents of the variable by not quoting it when you `echo` it. If `command` was the string `cd /tmp && echo *` it will echo the files in the current directory, not in `/tmp`. See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: to be clear `echo "$command" | bash`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why so many answers make it complicated!
use `alias` [command] 'string to execute'
example:

```
alias dir='ls -l'

./dir
[pretty list of files]
```

Comment: There are many problems with aliases. For one thing, they do not expand in scripts, which is obviously a bummer if you are writing a script (and thus your question is on-topic on Stack Overflow). For another, you can't pass positional arguments to aliases, just have them eat up the rest of your command line with no access to it. Also, the parsing rules are finicky, so you can't enable alias expansion and use the alias in the same command line. Bottom line, use a function, like everyone was telling you all along.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem with the following command:

##### `awk '{printf "%s[%s]\n", $1, $3}' "input.txt"`

I need to build this command dynamically:

The target file name `input.txt` is dynamic and may contain space.

The `awk` script inside `{}` braces `printf "%s[%s]\n", $1, $3` is dynamic.

#### Challenge:

1. Avoid extensive quote escaping logic if there are many `"` inside the `awk` script.
2. Avoid parameter expansion for every `$` field variable.

The solutions bellow with `eval` command and  associative `arrays` do not work. Due to `bash` variable expansions and quoting.

#### Solution:

Build `bash` variable dynamically, avoid `bash` expansions, use `printf` template.

```
 # dynamic variables, values change at runtime.
 input="input file 1.txt"
 awk_script='printf "%s[%s]\n" ,$1 ,$3'

 # static command template, preventing double-quote escapes and avoid variable  expansions.
 awk_command=$(printf "awk '{%s}' \"%s\"\n" "$awk_script" "$input")
 echo "awk_command=$awk_command"

 awk_command=awk '{printf "%s[%s]\n" ,$1 ,$3}' "input file 1.txt"
```

#### Executing variable command:

```
bash -c "$awk_command"
```

Alternative that also works

```
bash << $awk_command
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried various different methods:

```
printexec() {
  printf -- "\033[1;37m$\033[0m"
  printf -- " %q" "$@"
  printf -- "\n"
  eval -- "$@"
  eval -- "$*"
  "$@"
  "$*"
}
```

Output:

```
$ printexec echo  -e "foo\n" bar
$ echo -e foo\\n bar
foon bar
foon bar
foo
 bar
bash: echo -e foo\n bar: command not found
```

As you can see, only the third one, `"$@"` gave the correct result.

Comment: What is the explanation for that? Why only the third one? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58615498/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Not sure I care enough to investigate the intricacies of `eval`. IMO one of those 2 should have worked.

Answer (score -1):

Be *careful* registering an order with the: `X=$(Command)`

This one is still executed. Even before being called. To check and confirm this, you can do:

```
echo test;
X=$(for ((c=0; c<=5; c++)); do
sleep 2;
done);
echo note the 5 seconds elapsed
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the actual question here, and should probably be a comment instead (if even that).

Comment: What do you mean by *"registering an order"*? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Note: this script works only when u use Bash. So, don't remove the first line.

TUNECOUNT=$(ifconfig |grep -c -o tune0) #Some command with "Grep".
echo $TUNECOUNT                         #This will return 0 
                                    #if you don't have tune0 interface.
                                    #Or count of installed tune0 interfaces.
```

Comment: This stores the static string output from the command in a variable, not the command itself.

Comment: `grep -c -o` is not entirely portable; you would perhaps expect it to return the number of actual number of occurrences of the search expression, but at least GNU `grep` does not do that (it's basically equivalent to `grep -c` without the `-o`).

Comment: The Bash-only comment is weird; there is nothing in this simple script which isn't compatible with any Bourne-family shell.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, there are functions for this. But if you prefer variables then your task can be done like this:

```
$ cmd=ls

$ $cmd # works
file  file2  test

$ cmd='ls | grep file'

$ $cmd # not works
ls: cannot access '|': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'grep': No such file or directory
 file

$ bash -c $cmd # works
file  file2  test

$ bash -c "$cmd" # also works
file
file2

$ bash <<< $cmd
file
file2

$ bash <<< "$cmd"
file
file2
```

Or via a temporary file

```
$ tmp=$(mktemp)
$ echo "$cmd" > "$tmp"
$ chmod +x "$tmp"
$ "$tmp"
file
file2

$ rm "$tmp"
```

Comment: I suppose many people didn't notice the "First of all there are functions for this" you mentioned that is a correct pointer to the right direction IMHO: "Variables hold data. Functions hold code"

Comment: Your bash -c $cmd ad bash -c "$cmd" cases do two VERY different things! Try it each way with cmd='echo "$(pwd)"; cd test2; echo "$(pwd)"' To see why, do 'bash -x -c $cmd'.

Comment: Also: Functions are not a solution, They may be an alternative in some cases, but you have to construct the function! If you get the pieces of $cd as a series of $1, $2, etc., have fun turning it into a function, and then have even more fun not using eval to make use of it in another shell.

Answer (score -2):

As you don't specify any scripting language, I would recommand `tcl`, the [Tool Command Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) for this kind of purpose.

Then in the first line, add the appropriate shebang:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/tclsh
```

with appropriate location you can retrieve with `which tclsh`.

In `tcl` scripts, you can call operating system commands with `exec`.

Answer (score -8):

It is not necessary to store commands in variables even as you need to use it later. Just execute it as per normal. If you store in variables, you would need some kind of `eval` statement or invoke some unnecessary shell process to "execute your variable".

Comment: The command I will store will depend on options I send in, so instead of having tons of conditional statements in the bulk of my program it's a lot easier to store the command I need for later use.

Comment: @Benjamin, then at least store the options as variables, and not the command. eg `var='*.txt'; find . -name "$var"`