# How do I execute a command in a variable in Bash?

Tags: bash

If I have a script such as the below where I define a command to run in CMD_VAR, a variable, how do I get it executed in the same Bash script?

I do it this way because I want to log CMD_VAR to a file as well.

```
#!/bin/sh
CMD_VAR="echo hello world >> somelogfile"
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store a command in a variable in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615717/how-to-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-linux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you should not store redirections in a variable. And you should store commands in an array.

```
cmd=(echo "hello world")
log="somelogfile"
"${cmd[@]}" >> "$log"
```