# linux, start command (with switch user) stored in variable

Tags: shell, ksh, quoting

Whats wrong here? The echo shows the correct syntax.
Please help, thank you.

---

```
#!/bin/ksh
CMD="su - db2i72 -c 'db2 list utilities'" # or this
CMD="su - db2i72 -c \'db2 list utilities\'" # or this 
CMD="su - db2i72 -c \"db2 list utilities\"" # or this, always the same...

echo $CMD

$CMD
```

---

```
root@server:~ # ./test
su - db2i72 -c 'db2 list utilities'
Unmatched '.
```

Comment: what happens if u type in su - db2i72 -c 'db2 list utilities'

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: #!/bin/ksh
su - db2i72 -c 'db2 list utilities' -> works fine

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store a command in a variable in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615717/how-to-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store commands in functions, not variables. You don't have to worry about quoting at all if you use a function.

```
cmd() {
    su - db2i72 -c 'db2 list utilities'
}

cmd
```