# find with nested command reading blacklist

Tags: shell, sh

I have a script that recursively searches all directories for specific files or specific file endings.
These certain files I want to save the path in a description file.
Looks for example like this:

```
./org/apache/commons/.../file1.pom
./org/apache/commons/.../file1.jar
./org/apache/commons/.../file1.zip
```

and so on.

In a blacklist , I describe which file endings I want to ignore.

```
! -path "./.cache/*" ! -path "./org/*" ! -name "*.sha1" ! -name"*.lastUpdated"
```

and so on.

Now i want to read this blacklist file while the search to ignore the described files:

```
find . -type f $(cat blacklist) > artifact.descriptor
```

Unfortunately, the blacklist will not be included while the search.
When:

```
echo "find . -type f $(cat blacklist) > artifact.descriptor"
```

Result is as expected:

```
find . -type f ! -path "./.cache/*" ! -path "./org/*" ! -name "*.sha1" ! -name"*.lastUpdated" > artifact.descriptor
```

But it does not work or exclude the described files.
I tried with following command and it works, but i want to know why not with with find alone.

```
find . -type f | grep -vf  $blacklist  > artifact.descriptor
```

Hopefully someone can explain it to me :)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 1):

As tripleee suggests, it is generally considered bad practice to store a command in a variable because it does not catch all the cornercases.
However [you can use eval as a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615717/how-to-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-linux)

```
/tmp/test$ ls
blacklist  test.a  test.b  test.c
/tmp/test$ cat blacklist 
-not -name *.c -not -name *.b
/tmp/test$ eval "find . -type f "`cat blacklist`
./test.a
./blacklist
```

In your case I think it fails because the quotes in your blacklist file are considered as a literal and not as enclosing the patterns and I think it works if you remove them, but still it's probably not safe for other reasons.

```
! -path ./.cache/* ! -path ./org/* ! -name *.sha1 ! -name *.lastUpdated
```