# Simple Script Not Working

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a simple script that if a line has 7 commas in it, either true or false will be returned. But I'm running into a couple of errors. The first error is coming from the grep, if I remove the -o, I still receive the error. And I'm not sure why 0 is being displayed and why it's returning as false? I'm also having trouble with equal; as in neither -eq or == is working.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
str="a,g,5,d,s,c,f,s"
stat=grep -o "," <<< "$str" | wc -l
if [ $stat == '7' ];then
        echo "true"
else
        echo "false"
fi
```

Here is the output I'm receiving:

```
./tesh.sh
./tesh.sh: line 3: -0: command not found
0
./tesh.sh: line 4: [: ==: unary operator expected
false
```

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend. Lots of separate small bugs here, no individual bug to make a good SO question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/608639), [How to store a command in a variable in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5615717/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the below line in your script.

```
stat=$(grep -o "," <<< "$str" | wc -l)
```

Also correct you if condition like below as you are comparing with a numeric value

```
if [[ $stat -eq 7 ]];then
```

Comment: that's only part of it. `[ $stat == '7' ]` is wrong too; should be `[ "$stat" = 7 ]` to work reliably.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ... Strange, I would have used [[ $stat -eq 7 ]] since $stat should always be numerical.

Comment: The quotes are still important. If stat was empty, `[ $stat -eq 7 ]` would have a rather unuseful error.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I did not see that. Thanks.

Comment: @AndreGelinas, if you're going to use bash-only syntax, better to use `(( ))` to get into a proper numeric context so you can use `>`, `<`, `>=`, etc. for numeric comparisons.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here.

- `var=value somecommand arg1 arg2 ...` exports `var` in the environment in the context where `somecommand` is executed (without changing the environment for any future commands); it **doesn't** set `key` to the output of `somecommand`.
- `[ $stat == '7' ]` has multiple distinct issues:

  - `[` doesn't guarantee that `==` is a supported operation at all. [The POSIX `test` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) guarantees that `=` will be available for string comparisons, or `-eq` for numeric ones. (`[[` *does* guarantee support for `==`, and avoid the need for quotes; its use also explicitly disclaims portability to baseline `/bin/sh` implementations).
  - `$stat`, unquoted, can expand to an unknown number of words, depending on the current value of IFS and the contents of the variable. This means that if your `wc` command failed for some reason, you can end up running `[ = 7 ]` -- which yields your "unary operator unexpected" error -- not `[ "" = 7 ]`, which is correctly false. By contrast, the `7` doesn't need to be quoted -- it can't possibly expand to anything other than itself.

---

Instead of counting the number of commas, read your comma-separated items into an array, and count the number of array members. This can be done using only tools built into the shell itself, as documented in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) -- thus, with none of the (substantial) overhead of starting external executables such as `wc` or `grep`:

```
IFS=, read -r -a pieces <<<"$str"
if (( ${#pieces[@]} == 8 )); then
  echo "Correct number of pieces found"
else
  echo "Error: Only ${#pieces[@]} pieces found in line"
fi
```

This lets you refer to the items individually:

```
echo "This first piece is ${pieces[0]}"
echo "The last piece is ${pieces[7]}"
```