# How to dynamically build arguments that contain space in bash

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a script `find-files` that produces paths that can contain space in lines

```
/foo bar
/abc
```

I want to convert these paths to arguments that get to pass to another command `cmd` like this:

```
cmd -f "/foo bar" -f "/abc"
```

I tried this

```
cmd $(find-files | sed 's/^/-f /')
```

But it passes paths containing space as multiple arguments.

and if I quote the substitution, the whole string gets passed as a single argument.

What's the correct way of doing that?

BTW, this is not the same question as [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615717/how-to-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-a-shell-script), which suggested `eval`. `eval` doesn't help with dealing spaces at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop to build up the necessary array.

```
while IFS= read -r fname; do
  args+=(-f "$fname")
done < <(find-files)

cmd "${args[@]}"
```

This assumes that the file names cannot contain newlines, though, since `read` will treat such files as consecutive file names, not a single name. It's not clear if that is an issue for you, or if your `find-files` command can provide a safe alternative (such as output a null-separated list of file names, rather than lines).

Answer (score -1):

Put all your filenames in an array.

```
lst=( "/foo bar" /abc ) # quote as necessary
```

Then use `printf` to insert the `-f`.

```
cmd $( printf ' -f "%s"' "${lst[@]}" ) # leading space helps
```

For example,

```
$: echo $( printf ' -f "%s"' "${lst[@]}" )
-f "/foo bar" -f "/abc"
```

The leading space in front of the `-f` simplifies a bit.
Without it you get:

```
$: echo $( printf '-f %s' "${lst[@]}" )
bash: printf: -f: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

---

## EDIT:

Added double quotes inside the printf format.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, what echo got is "-f" "/foo" "bar" "-f" "/abc", since the printf cmd itself isn't quoted.

Comment: Added double quotes inside the printf format. Try that.

Comment: Good start, but the unquoted command substitution takes you back to square one.

Comment: If you quote the substitution then the entire set of arguments get passed as a single arg.