# executing string (ie $COMMAND) with escaped quotes doesn't give correct behavior

Tags: bash, escaping

If I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ARGUMENT in "$@"
do
    echo $ARGUMENT
done
```

and run

```
./test.sh "hello there" my name is
```

I get expected output:

```
hello there
my
name
is
```

Yet I'm trying to pass arguments from another script, and want to run the command:

```
COMMAND="./test.sh \"hello there\" my name is"
```

echo $COMMAND I get what's expected:

```
./test.sh "hello there" my name is
```

HOWEVER running $COMMAND doesn't seem to respect the escaped quotes:

$COMMAND

gives output:

```
"hello
there"
my
name
is
```

`"hello` and `there"` are seen as separate args...

I am probably not escaping something correctly. I expect the first output above, but I'm getting quotes in my output rather them being evaluated as a way to group the bash arguments. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a classic case of [How to store a command in a variable in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5615717/5291015) and what to do in those cases.

Comment: Store the constructs in an array i.e. `cmd=("./test.sh" "hello there" my name is)` and a quoted expansion `"${cmd[@]}"`. Assuming `test.sh` is made an executable