# Optionally include a user and password in curl request?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, shellcheck

I am optionally including a user and password in a curl request as follows:

```
declare creds=""
if [ -n "$user" ] && [ -n "$password" ]; then
    creds="-u ${user}:${password}"
fi

output=$(curl ${creds} -X PUT -v --write-out "%{http_code}" "$url" \
                  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -s -o /dev/null --data "${payload}")
```

This seems to work fine, but I'm getting this shellcheck warning:

```
Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting

https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086
```

Puting quotes around it doesn't work, e.g. if I do this:

```
output=$(curl "${creds}" -X PUT -v --write-out "%{http_code}" "$url" \
                  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -s -o /dev/null --data "${payload}")
```

then when the username and password are not supplied, this results in empty double quotes in the curl request `curl "" -X PUT ...`, which generates a `<url> malformed` error.

I could use an if-else for the curl command, but I'd rather avoid the duplication. Is the above approach acceptable despite the shellcheck warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were doing right in putting quotes around the variable, but `shellcheck` doesn't catch the issue of storing commands in a variable which has its own downfalls. Since this being a an issue with function of the shell, `shellcheck` can't quite catch it out-of-the-box. When you did below

```
creds="-u ${user}:${password}"
```

and quoted `"$creds"`, it is passed as one single argument word to `curl` instead of being broken down to `-u` and `"${user}:${password}"` separately. The right approach should have been to use an array to store the commands and expand it, so that the words are preserved and not split by the shell (foremost reason to quote the variable, as indicated by `shellcheck`)

```
creds=(-u "${user}:${password}")
```

and invoke

```
curl "${creds[@]}" <rest-of-the-cmd>
```

Also explore the following

1. [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)
2. [How to store a command in a variable in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5615717/5291015)

Comment: Thanks, and get rid of declare creds="" as well?

Comment: @Rory : Yes that’s not needed for an array, but if you want a clean  implementation, you can do creds=()