# docker exec curl post

Tags: bash, docker, curl

I would like to run curl inside a docker image. It is working in docker container like this:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel":"INFO"}'  localhost:8091/mobile-svc/actuator/loggers/something
```

when I want to run it from a bash script out from docker container like this:

```
args="sh -c \"curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{\"configuredLevel\":\"${LEVEL}\"}' localhost:${PORT}/mobile-svc/actuator/loggers/${PACKAGE}\""
echo $args
cmd="docker exec -it $CID $args"
eval $cmd
```

it said:

```
sh -c "curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel":"DEBUG"}' 
localhost:8091/tcp/mobile-svc/actuator/loggers/something
HTTP/1.1 404 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 08 Aug 2020 12:49:58 GMT
{"timestamp":"2020-08-08T12:49:58.949+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/tcp/mobile-svc/actuator/loggers/something"}
```

How can I pass compound parameters to curl?

thx
Zamek

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store a command in a variable in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44055875/10248678)

Comment: In general, you shouldn't need to script `docker exec` calls.  That's doubly true for something that's making a network call: run `curl` from your host connecting to the published port of the container.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: declare curl_args()

curl_args=("curl" "-i" "-X" "POST" "-H" "Content-Type: application/json" "-d" "{\"configuredLevel\":\"${LEVEL}\"}" "localhost:${PORT}/mobile-svc/actuator/loggers/${PACKAGE}")

declare cmd=("exec" "-it" "$CID" "sh" "-c" "\"${curl_args[@]}\"")

echo $cmd

eval $(docker ${cmd[@]}) 

the  seems good, but eval result is: 

curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

Comment: your `${PORT}` variable seems to resolve to `8091/tcp` which messes up your querystring. I guess you should use a variable that resolves to `8091` only to make it work.

Comment: I previously changed port with  ${PORT%\/tcp}. The echoed command like is that:
docker exec -it 649f6e6af264 sh -c curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel":"DEBUG"}' localhost:8091/mobile-svc/actuator/loggers/something

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the solving, but it is a little bit ugly:

```
cmd="docker exec -it $CID sh -c \"curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\\\"configuredLevel\\\":\\\"$LEVEL\\\"}' localhost:${PORT}/mobile-svc/actuator/loggers/something\""
```