# How to parametrize a variable value in shell script?

Tags: sh

I am a newbie to writing shell scripts. Please help me in parameterizing a variable value in my shell script.

I am taking command-line arguments for database name, server, user, and password in the following way:

```
database_name=$1
server=$2
user=$3 
password=$4
```

I want to understand how I can pass these values to a variable called sqlcmd. I pass these values in the following way and then echo to see the value of sqlcmd variable:

```
sqlcmd=sqlcmd -S $server -U $user -P $password
echo $sqlcmd
```

after making the shell script executable using chmod a+x  on ubuntu. I run the script and get the following error

`line 37: -S: command not found`. Line 37 in my shell script is a line on which sqlcmd variable is initialized

P.S I am using WSL on a remote windows machine. I am not sure if that should cause an error.

Comment: Is `sqlcmd` supposed to contain the command line, or the results of executing the command?

Comment: It is supposed to contain the command line.

Comment: What do you mean by "compile the shell script"?  Typically, you execute shell scripts and do not compile them.

Comment: It might help to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment/2268117#2268117.  When you omit the quotes, the line `sqlcmd=sqlcmd -S ...` attempts to run a command named `-S`.  There is an explanation for that in the link.

Comment: @WilliamPursell that was a mistake and I have fixed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store a command in a variable in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615717/how-to-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: Why are you not just executing the command?  If the only reason you are storing it in a variable is to `echo` the value before you run it, there are better mechanisms to achieve that. (eg, `set -x` or `set -v`)

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes:

```
sqlcmd="sqlcmd -S $server -U $user -P $password"
```

Note that you may run into difficulties later trying to *execute* the contents of `sqlcmd`.

Comment: Yes. I want to execute later the contents of sqlcmd so I do not want to implement the variable value in quotes.

Comment: I think to execute it after you have defined as chepner has stated, you need to wrap the next part in backticks e.g. `\`$sqlcmd\``

Comment: @Cameron that's just a [useless echo](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Comment: I'm not going to address that part of the question, aside from referring you [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).