# Systemctl bash variable

Tags: bash, ubuntu, variables, scripting

I'm trying to get this variable work, but I'm getting always an error about systemd-escape. Although I escape the special character, the variable is not working:

```
status="systemctl status syslog-ng | grep Active: | sed 's/.*: //' | sed 's/since.*//g'"
```

The result I'm getting is here:

```
Invalid unit name "|" was escaped as "\x7c" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
Invalid unit name "|" was escaped as "\x7c" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
Invalid unit name "'s/.*:" was escaped as "\x27s-.*:" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
Invalid unit name "|" was escaped as "\x7c" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
Invalid unit name "'s/since.*//g'" was escaped as "\x27s-since.*--g\x27" (maybe you should use systemd-escape?)
Unit \x7c.service could not be found.
Unit grep.service could not be found.
Unit Active:.service could not be found.
Unit \x7c.service could not be found.
Unit sed.service could not be found.
Unit \x27.mount could not be found.
Unit \x7c.service could not be found.
Unit sed.service could not be found.
● syslog-ng.service - System Logger Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/syslog-ng.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-10-11 14:01:23 CEST; 26min ago
     Docs: man:syslog-ng(8)
 Main PID: 3020944 (syslog-ng)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 101081)
   Memory: 8.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/syslog-ng.service
           └─3020944 /usr/sbin/syslog-ng -F -p /var/run/syslogd.pid

Oct 11 14:01:23 syslog-ng systemd[1]: Starting System Logger Daemon...
Oct 11 14:01:23 syslog-ng syslog-ng[3020944]: [2021-10-11T14:01:23.798405] Plugin module not found in 'module-path'; module-path='/usr/lib64/syslog-ng'>
Oct 11 14:01:23 syslog-ng syslog-ng[3020944]: [2021-10-11T14:01:23.801271] Plugin module not found in 'module-path'; module-path='/usr/lib64/syslog-ng'>
Oct 11 14:01:23 syslog-ng syslog-ng[3020944]: [2021-10-11T14:01:23.801828] Plugin module not found in 'module-path'; module-path='/usr/lib64/syslog-ng'>
Oct 11 14:01:23 syslog-ng syslog-ng[3020944]: [2021-10-11T14:01:23.808340] WARNING: With use-dns(no), dns-cache() will be forced to 'no' too!;
Oct 11 14:01:23 syslog-ng systemd[1]: Started System Logger Daemon.
```

I just want to have the status of my syslog-ng as a variable

Comment: `status=$(systemctl is-active syslog-ng )`

Comment: as a single command it would work, but as a variable I'm getting this: `-bash: active: command not found`

Comment: Why are you assigning a string, instead of executing a command? Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615717/how-to-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-a-shell-script and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 . `as a single command it would work, but as a variable` What do you mean by "single command" and what do you do with the variable?  You seem to be trying to execute the content of the varialble - don't, just print it. `status=$(systemctl is-active syslog-ng ) ; echo "$status"`. Check your scripts with shellcheck .

Comment: this `systemctl is-active syslog-ng`work but not this `status=$(systemctl is-active syslog-ng)`

Comment: status=$(systemctl is-active syslog-ng ) ; echo "$status" looks good to me

Comment: As an aside, the [`grep` is useless](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) and you should merge the two `sed` scripts; `systemctl status syslog-ng | sed -n '/Active: /!d;s///;s/since.*//p` (the `/g` flag could not possibly be useful here, either).

Answer (score 0):

We suggest to follow `systemd` [service unit definition documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).

As stated in the `Command lines` section.

> This syntax is inspired by shell syntax, but only the meta-characters and expansions described in the following paragraphs are understood, and the expansion of variables is different. Specifically, redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|", running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not supported.

We cannot assume `bash` nor `sh` syntax/rules writing `systemd` service unit.

Environment variables are better defined statically.

In case you need to store values in dynamic variables. We suggest create a script `service-unit-xyx.bash` that executes all the required assignments and eventually run the target service.

Using a single script `service-unit-xyx.bash` you can easily log and debug every line.

Eventually execute `service-unit-xyx.bash` script with full path in `ExecStart=` command.

Using execution script `service-unit-xyx.bash` also simplify the service unit development, from `systemd` service unit file to bash/sh script development.

It is also possible to use a `ExecStartPre=`, `ExecStartPost=` commands to control service runtime environments.

Read and follow sample service units from the internet.

**All commands/scripts should specify absolute path reference.**