# execute multiple commands assigned to a single variable - bash

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to ask the user to enter a command that will be executed, but I don't understand why I can't assign two commands to the same variable.

Here is the code:

```
user@localhost:~# read -ep "command: " cmd ; "$cmd"
```

and the result:

```
command: id ; date
-bash: id ; date : command not found
```

but if I type a single command, it works.

Thanks for your help

Comment: try wrapping the commands in double quotes, e.g. `command: "id ; date"`.

Comment: Storing commands in variables doesn't work very well. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and ["How can I store a command in a variable in a shell script?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615717/how-can-i-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: The shell interprets the "$cmd" as a single word command in this context. Since no command exists with the name `id ; date` it prints out a "command not found" message. As an important aside note; running directly user-supplied input (without validating it) is a dangerous business. Your code could be "fixed" by replacing `"$cmd"` with `eval "$cmd"`, but this is still dangerous and may not work at all with complex commands.

Comment: try this one: read -ep "command: " cmd ;  bash -c "$cmd"