# How do I set this find command to a variable in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I want the following assigned to a bash variable.

```
find . -name "*.zip" -exec echo {} ;
```

The below will throw warnings and errors, especially with the *(star).
Seems ok without the name argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
cmd="find . -name \"*.zip\" -exec echo {} ;"
$cmd
```

*`find: paths must precede expression: echo`*

I think it is the find command itself that is off?

Comment: Also see [BashFAQ/050 (I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: The problem with that duplicate is the accepted answer there tells how to do what was asked for instead of saying "don't do that".

Comment: A comment in answer above and the FAQ did give me workaround. set -x...to "print out command"

Comment: (As is regrettably common for questions tagged 'bash' on Stack Overflow) the accepted and extravagantly upvoted answer to the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615717/how-can-i-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-a-shell-script) is poor.  See [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17529220/4154375).