# Variable expansion that preserves empty argument

Tags: bash

I am executing the command `foo --bar "" --baz`, i.e. I'm calling `foo` with three arguments:

1. `--bar`
2. an empty string
3. `--baz`

This works.

Now, I would like to store that parameter sequence in a shell variable before passing it to `foo` (because I'm calling `foo` dozens of time with a varying list of parameters and I want that variable to hold the parameters common to all invocations), something along the lines of

```bash
PARAMS='--bar "" --baz'; foo ${PARAMS}
```

But I can't find a way to do that in a way that preserves all three parameters including the empty one. For example, the version above will pass three parameters to `foo`, but the middle one will be the string `""` (two double quotes) instead of an empty string.

Other approaches I tested where:

- `PARAMS="--foo \"\" --bar"; foo ${PARAMS}` also turns the second parameter into the string `""`
- `PARAMS="--foo   --bar"; foo ${PARAMS}` removes the second parameter
- `PARAMS="--foo   --bar"; foo "${PARAMS}"` coalesces the parameters into a single one `--foo   --bar`

Comment: Use an array. `PARAMS=( --bar "" --baz ); foo "${PARAMS[@]}"`.

Comment: Seems you are not yet familiar with [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and specifically **5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time**. And recall `eval` is just one character away from `evil` - use with caution.

Comment: Why not put the empty string into a new variable and hand that one to `foo`? Like `empty=""` and then `PARAMS='--foo $empty --bar'`. It might then work to use `eval "foo $PARAMS"`. I couldn't test this right now though.

Comment: Note that ALL_UPPERCASE variable names (like `PARAMS`) are best avoided because there is a danger of clashes with the large number of special ALL_UPPERCASE variables that are used in shell programming.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I store a command in a variable in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615717/how-can-i-store-a-command-in-a-variable-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array:

```
PARAMS=(--bar "" --baz)
foo "${PARAMS[@]}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with variables and keep your sanity, but with a shell function, it becomes trivial:

```
call_foo() {
  foo --bar '' --baz "$@"
}

call_foo with 'additional parameters'
```

`"$@"` expands to all parameters of the function, while preserving the original field splitting of the passed arguments.

This solution will not only work for bash, but any POSIX compliant shell.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Bash, an **array variable** is the standard solution.

Assign it like this:

```
PARAMS=(--bar "" --baz)
```

And expand it like this (the quotes are important!):

```
foo "${PARAMS[@]}"
```

See the section [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) in the Bash manual:

> Any element of an array may be referenced using `${name[subscript]}`.
> The braces are required to avoid conflicts with the shell’s filename
> expansion operators. If the *subscript* is ‘`@`’ or ‘`*`’, the word
> expands to all members of the array *name*. These subscripts differ
> only when the word appears within double quotes. If the word is
> double-quoted, `${name[*]}` expands to a single word with the value of
> each array member separated by the first character of the `IFS`
> variable, and `${name[@]}` expands each element of *name* to a
> separate word. When there are no array members, `${name[@]}` expands
> to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PARAMS` variable is actually holding a piece of shell syntax. It requires `eval` to process as such:

```
eval foo "$PARAMS"
```

Unfortunately, `eval` is a dangerous function which can render a script insecure.

If everything in `PARAMS` was carefully constructed by your script, such that no part of the material is an external input (in particularly, an untrusted input from "the wild"), you shouldn't have any problems.

knittl's answer is the best solution for this situation: calling a function with certain fixed parameters plus varying ones. It avoids `eval`; if you can avoid `eval`, you almost always should.